# Scintilla Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: scintilla

How do I make it appear as if it were automatic like the vertical one?

The window is 300 wide so I tried setting SCI_SETSCROLLWIDTH to 300 and then less than 300 with SCI_SETSCROLLWIDTHTRACKING turned on but the scrollbar will either still always show or not show at all.

Comment: Which port/binding of scintilla are you using?

Comment: SciLexer.DLL v:3.3.6 on Windows.

Comment: Scintilla doesn't directly support automatic horizontal scrollbar hiding, because it involves a potentially very expensive calculation (i.e. determining the longest line). Basically, you have to do it yourself - which can be quite tricky as there may be platform-specific issues that add further complications. I had a try with QScintilla, but couldn't get anything to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show/hide the horizontal SB, you need SCI_SETHSCROLLBAR(bool visible), but you need to know where the end of the line is. So you can try what I have below. It is fairly low impact since you are only looking at the currently visible lines.

Note that I use a Delphi wrapper for the scintilla control/DLL, but the calls can all be made with the regular scintilla messages (same basic names), and I have a few functions I use which are below as well. You could call this where you get the SCN_UPDATEUI message.

```
function GetFirstVisiblePos: Integer;
begin
    Result := PositionFromPoint(0,0);
end;

function GetLastVisiblePos: Integer;
begin
    Result := PositionFromPoint(clientwidth,clientheight);
end;

function GetFirstVisibleLine: Integer;
begin
    Result := LineFromPosition(GetFirstVisiblePos);
end;

function GetLastVisibleLine: Integer;
begin
    Result := LineFromPosition(GetLastVisiblePos);
end;

[...]

var
  i: integer;
  x, endPos: integer;
  needHSB: boolean;
begin  
    if not WordWrap then //Only need to do this if not wordwrapped
    begin

      x := ClientWidth ;
      needHSB := false;

      //Check currently visible lines only
      for i := GetFirstVisibleLine to GetLastVisibleLine do
      begin

        //GetXOffset adds left scroll spacing if we are already scrolled left some.
        endPos := PointXFromPosition(GetLineEndPosition(i) ) - x + GetXOffset ;

        needHSB := endPos > ClientWidth; 
        if needHSB then break; //once set, don't need to set again...

      end;

      SetHScrollBar( needHSB );

    end;
end;
```

Try that and that should do what you are after (if I read the original question correctly). It worked for me, although I was after something a little different originally.

I needed a way to try and control the horizontal scroll width which the sci control does not do automatically (for me anyway; SCI_SETSCROLLWIDTHTRACKING seems to be what you'd use for this but I was never able to get to work (at least in the way it implies it should work in the docs). I came up with the code below. In my app the code is in SCN_UPDATEUI message area.

```
    //Set new scroll width if there's a line longer than the current scroll
    //width can show:
    if not WordWrap then //Only need to do this if not wordwrapped
    begin

      //vars: i, x, endPos, LeftScrollPos : integer;

      x := ClientWidth ;

      //Check currently visible lines only
      for i := GetFirstVisibleLine to GetLastVisibleLine do
      begin

        //GetXOffset adds extra left scroll space if we are already scrolled left some.
        //24 is just a fudge factor to add a little visual space after a long line.
        endPos := PointXFromPosition(GetLineEndPosition(i) ) - x + GetXOffset + 24;

        if endPos > 2000 then //Greater than the control's default
        if endPos > ( GetScrollWidth ) then //Only need to proceed if we need more room
        begin
          LeftScrollPos := GetXOffset; //Store our current left scroll position
          SetScrollWidth( endPos ) ; //This sets left scroll to 0, so...
          SetXOffset( LeftScrollPos ); //Restore current left scroll position
        end;

      end;

    end;
```